# Error of display page with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i am using selenium to simulate a from .The problem now in the resulat page selenium confuse in displaying the value of text : it show me "parisl" in the first textFiled and "marseile" in the second. i can't understand what's the problem

This is my code

```
public class SeleniumExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
    // The Firefox driver supports javascript 


    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
     //  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     // And now use this to visit Google
     driver.get("http://www.voyages-sncf.com/");

     // Find the text input element by its name
     driver.findElement(By.name("origin_city")).sendKeys("paris");

     driver.findElement(By.id("train-destination-city")).sendKeys("marseille");



        Thread.sleep(4000);



     driver.findElement(By.id("train-book")).click();}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This coce should be working. Maybe I have one advice - but I have to make wild guess and guess that you are not English:

To be able to work with my selenium scripts and have proper key events, I had to make English keyboard as my default system layout. When I had my keyboard set up to Czech (my language), some key events were not working properly.

So assuming you use French layout, I advise you to switch it to English as default keyboard

Comment: i think it is problem caused by the autocomplete of the site

Answer (score 0):

When I open that page it redirects me to http://www.tgv-europe.com/ which doesn't have such an input tag as you are looking for above.

Maybe the website has some logic that redirects according to region?

P.S Not relevant to the original question, but an advice for you is to use implicit waits instead of doing a  Thread.sleep. Implicit waits will wait until the element you are looking for has appeared, unless your max time limit is reached.